# How to drag apps to the task tray?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I am trying to drag icons to my task tray using my galaxy s3 v4.0.4.
However when I am dragging the icons down to the tray the task icons dissappear and a bunch of options appear like info and delete. How can I pin apps. I have looked everywhere and not found a solution for this problem. Please help.!!

Comment: You want to add apps to bottom task tray, where message, phone etc shortcuts are present?

Comment: Click on the applications icon, then select menu > edit. You can now drag-and-drop any application icon you want (except for the applications icon)

Answer (score 1):

yea, but with the recent update, no option to do this, i thought that it was strange, so i got fed up and called samsung and they said with 4.0.4 that you actually can not place icons in the tray, fail samsung. all other previous versions allowed this, i would have assumed that this would be a standard thing, apparently not.

Comment: You can [install a different launcher](http://www.androidmadefun.com/androidfun/2012/8/10/if-you-dont-like-it-change-it-the-home-screen.html) that does support changing the tray icons.